# How can I tell what license I have on an install of SQL server, or Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, licensing

Is there any easy way to find out what license(s) are associated with a running copy of SQl Server, or Windows Server 2008?

I have technet subscriptions, and an MSDN subscription, but sometimes I also use a trial software if I need to quickly get a test environment up for a short amount of time. I have plenty of legal licenes for all the software (they are all just for test/development), but I don't accidentally want one of my 'trial licenses' to expire unexpectedly....how can I tell if I am running a trial version or not?

Comment: Just so everyone who reads this is clear, TechNet and MSDN software *does not* expire.  You can download 60-day trial versions from Microsoft's website that do expire after the timeout period.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but sometimes I do use trial software even though I have technet?MSDN licenses, (just so I don't have to bother going to the MSDN site and creating a license key), but your point is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 2008, I believe you can identify a trial version through looking at the System option of the Control Panel, then scroll down to Activation. If it is a trial, it should say something like "60 days to activate." Running winver from the command line should also tell you.

For SQL Server, I think if you go into SQL Server Management Studio then choose Help, About, it will display the days remaining on the right hand side.

Answer (score 7):

For SQL Server you can run the following query:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQL server the query is:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion, SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel, SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition, SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS EngineEdition; GO
```

see [SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx)
For Server 2008 the command is (from a command prompt)

cscript slmgr.vbs -dlv

Comment: You are missing a paren "(".

    SERVERPROPERTY 'ProductLevel')

Answer (score -1):

A handy tool I have used frequently is Magical Jellybean.  It pulls the license key for most MS software, as well as a slew of other popular programs.  You can check it out at http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder

Since we're a small company we use a lot of retail licenses along with volume licenses.  This tool makes it real handy identifying who has what.